# How to generate a deterministic SecureRandom for KeyPair generation?

Tags: java, android, cryptography

I need to generate a KeyPair based on a password entered by the user.

I would like to implement it as follows in Java (Android):

1. User enters password
2. A Key Derivation Function (e.g. PBKDF2) is used to generate a seed
3. Seed is used for a PseudoRandomNumberGenerator (PRNG), which based on the seed generates deterministic values
4. The PseudoRandomNumberGenerator is used by KeyPairGenerator to generate an asymmetric KeyPair.

Also see https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1665

My problem is at step 3 and 4. To initialize a [KeyPairGenerator](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyPairGenerator) with a source of randomness a [SecureRandom](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyPairGenerator.html#initialize(java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec,%20java.security.SecureRandom) is used. It is possible to [seed](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/SecureRandom.html#setSeed(byte[])) the SecureRandom but this wont make the SecureRandom predictable which is intended behaviour.

I found different suggestions to work around this:

1. Use "SHA1PRNG" as algorithm for SecureRandom

   - On older android devices the implementation of SHA1PRNG is broken and only uses the seed from setSeed.
   - -> The implementation differs on different platform therefore this cannot be used.
2. Wrapper arround different PRNG which extends SecureRandom

   1. Extend SecureRandom
   2. Overwrite all methods and point them to different PRNG.

      - Is there already an PRNG implementation that I can use?
      - I took a look at the `org.spongycastle.crypto.prng` package. Is it e.g. possible to build a deterministic SecureRandom by using the SP800SecureRandomBuilder?

In general what is the best way to implement a deterministic SecureRandom for KeyPair generation on Android?

Comment: `javax.crypto` offers a lot of additional functionality next to `java.security`, maybe have a look at some classes there

Comment: This question keeps popping up. I have to say that it's almost always the result of bad design decisions. It's better to generate a truly random keypair and encrypt the private key with password-based crypto than to deterministically generate a keypair from a password seed.

Comment: Nevertheless, there is an example in Bouncycastle called [FixedSecureRandom](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/prng/FixedSecureRandom.html) which you can use as an example of extending SecureRandom to remove the entropy. The only methods you need to override are `setSeed()` and `nextBytes()`.